# Div Hovering Over Another Div - Height/Width

Tags: html, hover

I am attempting to have one div hovering over another div full of content.  This can be done using position:absolute and z-index.  The problem is I want the hovering div to be the same height and width of the div full of content.

I've tried 100% height and width, but since I wrote:

```
<div class=hover></div><div id=content>FULL OF CONTENT</div>
```

the hover div doesn't recognize what the height and width of the content div is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the hovering div *inside* the other div:

```
/* CSS */
#content {
  position: relative;
}
.hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

<div id="content">
  Content goes here.
  <div class="hover">
  </div>
</div>
```

The hover div may be only over the content. If you set any borders or margins on the outer div, the hover div will not cover that.

Comment: Thanks, I believe my only mistake was I didn't put position:relative on the outer div, cause I did try putting the hoverdiv on the inside.  Let me try this and see if it works for me.

Comment: Yes, the relative is important. The hover div will be positioned absolute to the first parent that has a position as well. If you don't add `position: relative` to the parent div, the hover div will positioned absolute to the body.

Comment: Now I am just trying to show content through the div if I put a hover style on the hover div.  I know I can do transparent, but IE is pretty bad about transparencies!